# how to know the positioning of collectionview cell on the device screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

hi i am new to the ios development, I am using `collectionview` that shows one cell at a time and scrolls horizontally (like a gallery), what I am trying to do is to change the labels present on my screen when the cells are being scrolled and cell 0 and cell 1 are being displayed on the screen half-half.
Currently the text in labels change when the scrolling gets stopped.
I am using `func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`

Edit 1:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: imageCollectionView.contentOffset, size: (imageCollectionView.bounds.size))
    let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
    let indexPath : IndexPath = imageCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)!
    lblUserName.text = arrayImageData[indexPath.row]["userName"] as! String?
    lblTime.text = arrayImageData[indexPath.row]["time"] as! String?
    imgProfilePic.kf.setImage(with: arrayImageData[indexPath.row]["profilePic"] as! Resource?)
}
```

Comment: You are really close! There is another method in the delegate that will propably fit your needs - `scrollViewDidScroll` - https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll

Comment: @Loisiowaty
please check the Edited part of question , when i right the same code in `scrollViewDidScroll` i get a BAD_EXCESS crash on `let indexpath` line

Comment: That's most likely because you force unwrap (`!`) the return value of `indexPathForItem` - when the point is between the cells, the value can be `nil` - you need to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement `scrollViewDidScroll` instead.